# Python the whole Module

Tags: python

Normally when you execute a python file you do python ***.py

but if the whole Module which contain many .py files inside

for example  MyModule contain many .py file and if I do

`python -m MyModule $*` what would happen as oppose python individual python file?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confusing *package* with *module*. A python module is always a single .py file. A package is essentially a folder which contains a special module always named `__init__.py`, and one or more python modules. Attempting to execute the package will simply run the `__init__.py` module.

Answer (score 1):

It runs the code in the

```
MyModule/__init__.py
```

file.  Print sys.argv in that file to see what the shell is giving you in terms of command line arguments.  $* is meaningless in this context unless you're in a shell script (I believe)?